# Condition Distribution of $~X~$ given $~X<2Y~$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

> Suppose that $~X,~ Y~$ are independent exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$.
>
> For $a > 0$, find $P (X > a|X < 2Y )$. What is the conditional distribution (give the name and any parameter(s)) of $X$ given that $X < 2Y$ ?

**Attempt**

I have calculated that $P (X > a|X < 2Y ) = \frac{3 e^{-\lambda a}-1}{2}$.

---

**Question**

What distribution does $P (X > a) = \frac{3 e^{-\lambda a}-1}{2}$ represent?

Comment: Might pay to check your calculations.  For instance, if $a=\log(9)/\lambda$, you get $\frac{3e^{-\lambda a}-1}{2}=-\frac{1}{3}$, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I used online calculator to check my answer and it gives the same answer. https://www.symbolab.com/solver/double-integrals-calculator/%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D%5Ccdot%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cint_%7Ba%7D%5E%7B2%5Ccdot%20y%7D%20b%5E%7B2%7D%5Ccdot%20e%5E%7B-b%5Ccdot%20x%7D%5Ccdot%20e%5E%7B-b%5Ccdot%20y%7D%20dxdy

Comment: You've ignored the fact that sometimes, $a>2y$.  That integral will include such regions with negative weight, rather than leaving them out.  Basically, $0$ shouldn't be the lower bound on $y$.

Comment: If $x>a$ and $x<2y$, then necessary $2y>a$ must be true.

Comment: So how do you suggest to solve the problem?

Comment: Literally replace the lower bound $y=0$ with the lower bound $y=\frac{a}{2}$. Now you have the right integral and can get the right value; then you can look it up in your probability distributions.

Comment: That solves the problem. Thank you for pointing that out! The result I got is $e^{-\frac{3\lambda}{2}a}$. Therefore, it is exponential distribution with rate $\frac{3}{2}\lambda$ right?

Comment: Yes. For $a>0$ we have: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>a\mid X<2Y)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(a<X<2Y)}{\mathsf P(X<2Y)}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_a^\infty\int_{x/2}^\infty\lambda^2\exp(-\lambda (x+y))~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y }{\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\int_{x/2}^\infty\lambda^2\exp(-\lambda (x+y))~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y }\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_a^\infty \lambda\exp(-3\lambda x/2)\mathrm d x }{\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\lambda \exp(-3\lambda x/2)~\mathrm d x}\\[2ex]&=\exp(-3 a\lambda/2)\end{align}$$

Comment: So post that as your answer -- or have @NickPeterson post his suggestions -- and accept it.